# NULL pointer dereference in Linux input driver

Tags: c, linux, input, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

```
//Init Module
...
set_bit(EV_ABS, joystick_dev->evbit);

set_bit(ABS_X, joystick_dev->absbit);
set_bit(ABS_Y, joystick_dev->absbit);
set_bit(ABS_Z, joystick_dev->absbit);
...

//Kernel Thread
...
int g[3];

g[0] = -1;
g[1] = 0;
g[2] = 0;

input_report_abs(joystick_dev, ABS_X, g[0]);
input_report_abs(joystick_dev, ABS_Y, g[1]);
input_report_abs(joystick_dev, ABS_Z, g[2]);

input_sync(joystick_dev);
...
```

The execution abruptly stops at

```
input_report_abs(joystick_dev, ABS_Y, g[1]);
```

after executing

```
input_report_abs(joystick_dev, ABS_X, g[0]);
```

and throws the following exception  -

```
BUG: unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference...
```

What could be the error? Thank you.

Comment: Please show the prototype for `input_report_abs()`, the declaration for `g[]` and where you assign to `g[0 .. 2]`.

Comment: First, you need to post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Second, the problem is exactly what it sounds like: you're taking a NULL pointer and trying to use it as if it were pointing to valid data, which it isn't. We also don't know what anything there is, other than names, which don't necessarily say anything about the actual contents they hold.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to assign value to the `g[0]`.

```
// Kernel Thread ... int g[3];

g[1] = -1; g[2] = 0; g[3] = 0;
```

`int g[3]` means `g[0],g[1],g[2]` right? Fix that hope you will get what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in Linux, while registering ABS events, we need to set their parameters, which is *not* the case for Relative and Keyboard events. So we need to add this.

```
input_set_abs_params(joystick_dev, ABS_X, 0, 255, 4, 8);
input_set_abs_params(joystick_dev, ABS_Y, 0, 255, 4, 8);
input_set_abs_params(joystick_dev, ABS_Z, 0, 255, 4, 8);
```

Now it will work just fine. This is documented here:

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/input/input-programming.txt